# Tkinter strange Frame Size

Tags: python, size, tkinter, frame

I get this strange behaviour of the second frame. How do I resize the "Clone Repo" and "Pull" Buttons to the full column size? A picture of the output:

[image: example]

source:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Frame()
root.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W)

local=LabelFrame(root, text="local")
local.grid(row=0, sticky=E+W)
external=LabelFrame(root, text="external")
external.grid(row=1, sticky=E+W)

StatusButton=Button(local, text="status")
StatusButton.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)

AddFileEntry=Entry(local)
AddFileEntry.grid(row=1, column=0)

AddFileButton=Button(local, text="add changed/new file(s)")
AddFileButton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W+E)

CommitEntry=Entry(local)
CommitEntry.grid(row=2, column=0)

CommitButton=Button(local, text="Comment on changes")
CommitButton.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W+E)

CloneRepoEntry=Entry(external)
CloneRepoEntry.grid(row=0, column=0)

CommitRepoButton=Button(external, text="Clone repo")
CommitRepoButton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W+E)

PushButton=Button(external, text="Push")
PushButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)

PullButton=Button(external, text="Pull")
PullButton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W+E)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural size of the widgets in the bottom frame are smaller than the frame. Tkinter needs to know how/where to allocate the extra space.  You can tell it this information by giving a columm and/or row "weight".

In your case, giving column 1 of `external` a weight of 1 will cause it to expand to fill the empty space in the frame.

```
external.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```